# UK Business Visa

Tags: visa, business

We have just registered our company in the uk. My partner and co-director is a non uk citizen. He is Zimbabwean. What kind of visa does he need to be able to come to the uk for the purpose of negotiating business deals with African region customers and meet UK business suppliers.

Comment: How much time does your partner want to spend in the UK?

Answer (score 2):

Negotiating deals and attending meetings are both permitted under the [standard visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview).  As long as your partner doesn't want to stay in the UK for more than six months at a time, or to spend more than half of his time in the UK, that's the visa he should apply for.